# Generate LLVM bitcode for android aosp

Tags: android, llvm, android-source, bitcode

Would anyone please give me a pointer that how can I generate LLVM bitcode for Android aosp?

I have changed the following in the build/core/clang/clear_vars.mk:

```
LOCAL_CLANG_CFLAGS:=-emit-llvm -S
LOCAL_CLANG_CPPFLAGS:=-emit-llvm -S 
LOCAL_CLANG:=true
```

However, the aosp build failed with this set up.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: 41 warnings generated.
target thumb C++: libbluetooth_jni <= packages/apps/Bluetooth/jni/com_android_bluetooth_a2dp.cpp
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8//sysroot/usr/lib/Scrt1.o(.text+0x20): error: undefined reference to 'main'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/checkseapp_intermediates/checkseapp] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....